# How to represent in typescript a list of objects where the key is the date and the content is an array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic4

I am racking my brain to represent the following data set in typescript:
[image]

I'm trying as follows, but I get an error in ReactJs.

```
interface IDose {
  name: string;
  date: string;
}

interface IVaccine {
  [date: string]: IDose[]
}

const [data, setData] = useState<IVaccine[]>([]);

...

<IonGrid>
  <IonRow>
    {data.map((d, i) => {
      return (
        <IonCol key={i}>
          <IonButton>
            {d.date}
            <br />
            {d.name}
          </IonButton>
        </IonCol>
      );
    })}
  </IonRow>
</IonGrid>
```

Error: Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function...

Could anyone give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do see a few issues with your code.

First and foremost, the `data` state does not seem to be an array of object, thus Array.map() won't work if you wish to iterate through the keys and print their respective values. Therefore, if you wish to iterate through data and print the values within it, you might want to use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) instead. That being said, you should define the typings for `state` as an object (dictionary), rather than an array of objects.

This are the changes you should make:

```
interface IDose {
  name: string;
  date: string;
}

interface IVaccine {
  [date: string]: IDose[]
}

// here
const [data, setData] = useState<IVaccine>();

...

<IonGrid>
  <IonRow>
    // and here
    {data && Object.values(data).map((d, i) => {
      return (
        <IonCol key={i}>
          <IonButton>
            {d.date}
            <br />
            {d.name}
          </IonButton>
        </IonCol>
      );
    })}
  </IonRow>
</IonGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In the end, I still need to make another map. But everything worked out.

Answer (score 0):

**First, create a new object class for your array object.**

```
export class Object {
    name: string;
    date: string; //or Date
}
```

**then, create the data structure**

```
let objectMap : Map<string (date string), Object[]> = new Map<string, Object[];
```

However...do you need an additional date field when the key is already the date? I feel like you can simply use the key as the date for the named field.